# wordpress if post is in_category display category name

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check if a Wordpress post has category 'X, Y or Z' and if so display the name(s) of the category ('X Y or Z').

I already check and get a true of the category, but how can I show each name that has been found in_category();

```
if ( in_category( array( 'X', 'Y', 'Z') {
echo "yes";
}
```

How can I display the category name?

Comment: Try using get_the_category( int $post_id) function

Comment: Tried, gave me an " unexpected '$post_id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' "

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer to your question is this

```
get_the_category();
```

Using your example you can say

```php
if (in_category( array('X', 'Y', 'Z') )) {
    echo get_the_category();
}
```

> This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post ID as the parameter.

For more information and usage of `get_the_category()` visit the next [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting an Array output, because I have the product brand and other categories selected. I only want to show the product brand name(s) only.